# VBA less than operator for cells.value not working correctly

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, less

I try to give out a value using usual less operator in excel VBA. So I would like to give out the value 18 every time the value in one cell is less than 8 and greater than 0. Else "Empty" shall be printed out. This shall only work for specific rows where some columns are not empty. Here my code snippet:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns(22).NumberFormat = "0.00"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns(23).NumberFormat = "0.00"

For x = 2 To LastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, "E")) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, "F")) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, "G")) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, "H")) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, "I")) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, "J")) Then
        If Cells(x, "V").Value <= "8" And Cells(x, "V").Value > "0" Then
        Cells(x, "AA").Value = "18"
        Else: Cells(x, "AA").Value = "Empty"
        End If
    End If

Next x
```

The code only works for cells with value 9, other than that it always gives out 18, even though the number is much higher than 8.

I check also the debugger and it says Value/Double as type and the correct value of the cells. But anyways the macro enters 18.

Comment: If you're comparing numbers, do `8` instead of `"8"`

Comment: I knew it was something stupid but that I didn't expect. :D Now it's working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome Darijo! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using string values ("8", "0", "18", "Empty") in your comparison and assignment statements instead of numeric values. This is causing unexpected results as string comparison is different from numeric comparison.

Try using numeric values instead of strings. Also, you can simplify your code using the "And" operator to combine the cell empty checks, and use the `ElseIf` statement to avoid unnecessary comparisons. Here's an updated code snippet:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns(22).NumberFormat = "0.00"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns(23).NumberFormat = "0.00"

For x = 2 To LastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, "E")) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, "F")) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, "G")) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, "H")) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, "I")) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, "J")) Then
        If Cells(x, "V").Value > 0 And Cells(x, "V").Value < 8 Then
            Cells(x, "AA").Value = 18
        ElseIf Cells(x, "V").Value >= 8 Then
            Cells(x, "AA").Value = "Empty"
        End If
    End If
Next x
```